# Alinear y separar correctamente dos funciones HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, web

Tengo un encabezado que muestra un título y un contador de tiempo estimado de lectura realizado con simple HTML y CSS. El problema es que los mismos se encuentran desalineados y quiero intentar que se muestren correctamente independientemente de la resolución del dispositivo.

Les dejo imágenes y el código.

> Así es como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la versión móvil de la página se muestra de la anterior manera.

En la siguiente imagen muestro lo que quisiera corregir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Simplemente que el título se muestre separado del contador de tiempo estimado.

> Código:

```css
  .title {
        padding: 20px 36px;
        background: radial-gradient(circle,#e9f6fb 0.10%,#f1f1f1);
        border-radius: 25px;
        box-shadow: rgba(68,68,68,0.20) 0 3px 50px 0;
        }
        .estimated-time {
        color: #32323a;
        cursor: default;
        float: right;
        font-size: 17px;
        text-align: center;
        user-select: none;
        }
        .url {
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #32323a;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
```

```html
<div class="title">
    
    <h2 style="font-size:20px">
    
    <strong class="estimated-time"><em class="fa-stopwatch far" style="padding-right:5px">&nbsp;</em>2'</strong>
    
    <a class="url" href="https://www.example.com/">Example title</a>
    
    </h2>

    </div>
```

Es un código demasiado sencillo, pero no logro resolver este problema, si sabes de algo se agradece mucho.

Comment: Para manejar la posición del contenido de manera dinámica (especialmente con dispositivos móviles), te recomiendo que uses flexbox. Este es un [buen tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) pero está en inglés. También puedes echarle un [ojo a este en español](https://lenguajecss.com/css/maquetacion-y-colocacion/flexbox/). Mucha suerte!

Comment: Los elementos `<strong>` y `<a>` son elementos inline. Si los quieres en líneas separadas hazlos `display:block;` Además el `<strong >` tiene `float: right;` Utiliza `text-align:right` y borra el float

Answer (score 0):

Según entendí quieres ordenar el contador respecto al titulo, entonces no es mas fácil crear un div aparte que contenga el contador y ese alinearlo

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguirlo utilizaremos `flexbox`, lo primero será modificar la estructura `HTML` para que el padre flex tenga dos hijos.

Llegado a este punto tendremos dos especies de columnas (por los dos hijos), pero su espacio se dividirá a partes iguales, por lo cual le asignaremos la propiedad `flex-grow` en 1 al hijo que queremos que se estire para ocupar el espacio disponible.

El código se verá algo así, puedes leer más de flexbox acá: [Conceptos Básicos de flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)

```css
.title {
        padding: 20px 36px;
        background: radial-gradient(circle,#e9f6fb 0.10%,#f1f1f1);
        border-radius: 25px;
        box-shadow: rgba(68,68,68,0.20) 0 3px 50px 0;
        display: flex;
        }
        .grow-1{
            flex-grow: 1;
        }
        .estimated-time {
        color: #32323a;
        cursor: default;
        float: right;
        font-size: 17px;
        text-align: center;
        user-select: none;
        }
        .url {
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #32323a;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <h2 style="font-size:20px" class="grow-1">
            <a class="url" href="https://www.example.com/">El 63 % de los uruguayos aprueba la gestión del presidente luis lacalle pou</a>
        </h2>
        <strong class="estimated-time"><em class="fa-stopwatch far" style="padding-right:5px">&nbsp;</em>2'</strong>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```